# How can I connect to my TI-89 calculator?

Tags: usb, calculator

I'd like to transfer data to and from my TI-89 Titanium that connects via a USB cable.

How can I do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to research you can access the data on the TI-89 by using a program called `tilp` which you can install from the repositories. See more information here:

http://ohioloco.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=220045

There was some issue with permissions, but if you get the error, just use sudo.

There is also another program which might be useful to you called CalcForgeLP, this has support for the TI-89, but had some hicups with the new usb library. Maybe it's fixed. See more details here:

http://tichessteamhq.yuku.com/topic/4749/t/TI89-Titanium-USB-Protocol.html